# Prove that $2^{n+2}a_n \le \pi \le 2^{n+2}b_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $a_0=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-a_n^2}}$ and $b_0=1$ and $b_{n+1}=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+b_n^2}}{b_n}$.
>   Prove that $2^{n+2}a_n \le \pi \le 2^{n+2}b_n$.

I have proved the that $\pi \le 2^{n+2}b_n$. Here is how I did to prove it:
We have $b_0=1\ge 1$. Assume that $b_n\ge 1$ for every $n$ and we should prove it for $b_{n+1}$. We have $b_n^2\le 1+b_n^2$ so $1\le\dfrac{\sqrt{1+b_n^2}}{b_n}=b_{n+1}$, hence $1\le b_{n-1}^2(\sqrt{8}+1)$, so$$
1+b_{n-1}^2\le b_{n-1}^2(\sqrt{8}+2)\\
b_n^2\le\sqrt{8}+2\\
(b_n^2-2)^2\le 8\\
b_n^4-4b_n^2+4\le 8\\
b_n^2\le \dfrac{4}{b_n^2}+4\\
b_n\le2\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{b_n^2}+1}\\
b_n\le2b_n+1$$
And since $2^2\ge \pi$, the inequality is true for every $n$. But now I do not know how to prove the other side.

Comment: Hint: If $0<x<1$, then $\sqrt x>x$

Comment: yeah i know that but it doesn t seem useful for me

Comment: Try to manipulate $a_{n+1}$ using this fact

Comment: should I find the value of $a_{n+1}$ in expression of $a_{n}$

Comment: I believe the recursion for $b_n$ should have been $b_{n+1}=\frac{\color{red}{-1}+\sqrt{1+b_n^2}}{b_n}$, in such a way that the wanted inequality is equivalent to $\sin\theta < \theta < \tan\theta$ for $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4\cdot 2^n}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio nooo